# Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, submit

I'm trying so send a form (using a directive) when a property in the model changes (so I watch the property), but when I trigger the submit event, I get the error: "Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress", how can I avoid this error, here is my code:

```
app.directive("autoSubmit", function(){
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){

      scope.$watch("valid", function(){ 
        if(scope.valid == 1) {
          console.log("send form");
          element.triggerHandler("submit");
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Heres is he plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/cosJLkhUEKv55G8uU1Ea (to reproduce the error, just change the value of the textbox to 1)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: did you change the value of the textbox to 1?

Comment: Ah, yes, now I get it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that there is already a $digest cycle running (obviously `watch` one) when you try to trigger an event. So you should simply wait until its done and raise the event during the next one. You can `$timeout` service for that:

```
app.directive("autoSubmit", function($timeout) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch("valid", function() {
                if (scope.valid == 1) {
                    console.log("send form");
                    $timeout(function() {
                        element.triggerHandler('submit');
                    })
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/bRXfi9kFVFICgFUFvtZz?p=preview

Another way around is to invoke `ngSubmit` function manually yourself using `$parse` service:

```
app.directive("autoSubmit", function($parse) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch("valid", function() {
                if (scope.valid == 1) {
                    console.log("send form");
                    var submitHandler = $parse(attrs.ngSubmit)(scope);
                    if (submitHandler) {
                        submitHandler();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/vNI8OwfnxSQJ6tQLpFqZ?p=preview

Comment: Thank you very much @dfsq... did you see any drawback or advantage using any of those implementation?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't hardcode value `1` into directive, it's not very flexible.

Comment: Ok, actually that was just for illustration purposes :P ... thanks again.

Comment: Works Great, But this timeout is safe to use?

Comment: @Jordan Yes, it's guaranteed that $timeout callback will be invoked during the next digest cycle, so it's safe.

Comment: @dfsq Thanks, works perfectly. I wrapped my scope apply function by timeout function.

Answer (score 1):

when you start a process and do not kill it you receive digest is already in progress , for solving that problem you must kill process using $timeout service 
after specific time .

Comment: Although your hints may be helpful, I'd suggest to elaborate your answer (provide some code with the method you mentioned). Best regards.